# how can i position content at specified position in itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I just started using this library.
How can i position text in a cell at middle and at bottom?

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Test").setFont(font);

Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(1)).useAllAvailableWidth();
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setMinHeight(100);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
cell.add(para);
cell.add(new Paragraph("test")).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Currently setting the vertical alignment the content is aligned to the bottom. The output:
[image: The output]

How can I achieve the position of text at middle and bottom?
Like this with in the same cell:

[image: output]

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `setHorizontalAlignment`?

Comment: I just need to align the content to the left end of the cell however setHorizontalAlignment does not set the content as required

Comment: I misunderstood. Maybe try 3 rows (cells) and align the 2nd to middle and the 3rd to bottom. Note that in your example you call setVerticalAlignment on the cell, not the paragraph, so your 2nd call overrides the first one.

Comment: @Reto Hohener Thanks,that worked out with using three cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Test").setFont(font);
    
Table table = new 
Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(1)).useAllAvailableWidth();
table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
table.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setMinHeight(100);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
cell.add(para);
cell.add(new Paragraph("test")).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: the code sets the content at the middle and bottom of the cell